# flask & jinja2 & 0 & None

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

This is a pretty routine thing I do:

`{{ data['key'] or '' }}` so it won't display `None`, but it also won't display a `0` and sometimes-- most of the time-- I really need `0` values to show, but never a `None`.

What's the easiest fix for this? Something like `{{ data['key']|none('') }}` where `none` is a filter returning a blank if the value is `None`?

Or something checking for a non-`None` value inside the `{{ ... }}` tags? What's your quick fix here?

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ data['key'] if data['key']!=None else '' }}
```

Comment: yeah.. that'll do, just not as clean as the old `or ''`

Comment: you can add `else ' '`

Comment: `is not None` is the canonical way. `is`/`is not` compares by identity (=memory address) rather than by value, and there's only one `None` object.